# I am working with a large dataset. Each value in the data needs to be cleaned. how can i do it using filter or query function in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

My data set looks like the below one:

| BKG_PRODTN_DT | POL_EXP_INFO | BKD_MAJ_LINE_CD | POL_SYM_CD | AMT | bkd_amt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20210319,20210319 | 100,100 | A001,A001 | NVA,NVA | 14.26,14.26 | 10,13.97 |
| 20210319,20210319 | 101,101 | A111,A112 | NVA,NVA | 63,64.17 | 62.89,62.89 |

I am expecting a data frame like the below one.

| BKG_PRODTN_DT | POL_EXP_INFO | BKD_MAJ_LINE_CD | POL_SYM_CD | AMT | bkd_amt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20210319 | 100 | A001 | NVA | 14.26 | 10,13.97 |
| 20210319 | 101 | A111,A112 | NVA | 63,64.17 | 62.89 |

Each value in the dataframe needs to be transformed. There are two values in each cell of the dataframe which are separated by a delimiter(,). I want to check if both the values in a cell are equal. If they are same/equal, I want to delete the second value, else(if the values in each cell separated by a delimiter are different), i want to leave the actual value in the cell as it was. Can i do this using query function in pandas.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
print(df.replace(r"^(.*),\1$", r"\1", regex=True))
```

Prints:

```
  BKG_PRODTN_DT POL_EXP_INFO BKD_MAJ_LINE_CD POL_SYM_CD       AMT   bkd_amt
0      20210319          100            A001        NVA     14.26  10,13.97
1      20210319          101       A111,A112        NVA  63,64.17     62.89
```

Comment: Thanks for your response @Andrej Kesely It is not displaying the expected output. It displayed the actual output.

Comment: @Neel333 I've tested it with the input you have in question and it produces output I have in my answer. Is your values of type `list` or strings?

Comment: they are of type strings in a dataframe.

From code: 
BKG_PRODTN_DT         object
POL_EXP_INFO          object
POL_ID                object
BKD_MAJ_LINE_CD       object
POL_SYM_CD            object
PREM_TRANS_TYPE_CD    object
TRANS_RSN_CD          object
SUM(CASH_PREM_AMT)    object
BKD_PREM_AMT          object
BKD_AMT               object
dtype: object

Comment: @Neel333 But what is this `object`? String or list of strings?

Comment: Yes that is a string.